# Wkhtmltopdf + cakepdf - Custom page size

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, wkhtmltopdf

I can't figure out how to enable custom page sizes with CakePDF and wkhtmltopdf. I have the following configuration code:

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
  'engine' => [
      'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
      'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  ],
  'orientation' => 'portrait',
  'pageSize' => '', // this line
  'download' => true
]);
```

I want to have 150x150mm pages. I already tried several things like passing an array [150,150] but also things like '150 150' or '150mm 150mm'. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CakePDF `pageSize` option maps to the `page-size` option of wkhtmltopdf, which takes `QPrinter::PaperSize` constant names, like for example `A4`, `A5`, `B0`, `B1`, `Legal`, `Letter`, etc., ie you cannot define a custom size using that option.

If you need a custom size, then you have to use the wkhtmltopdf specific `page-width` and `page-height` options, which both take millimeter values by default.

Quote from the wkhtmltopdf docs:

> Page sizes:
>
> The default page size of the rendered document is A4, but using this
>    --page-size option this can be changed to almost anything else, such as: A3,
>    Letter and Legal. For a full list of supported pages sizes please see
>    http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum.
>
> For a more fine grained control over the page size the --page-height and
>    --page-width options may be used

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => [
        'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
        'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
        'options' => [
            'page-width' => 150,
            'page-height' => 150
        ]
    ],
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true
]);
```

See also

- **[wkhtmltopdf docs](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)**
- **[Qt Documentation > QtGui > QPrinter > enum QPrinter::PaperSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum)**

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf does support custom page sizes. I'm not sure if cakepdf will work with them, but if it just passes the arguments to wkhtmltopdf then it should. You can do it like this:

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
  'engine' => [
      'className' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
      'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  ],
  'orientation' => 'portrait',
  'page-width' => '4in'
  'page-height' => '6in'
  'download' => true
]);
```

You can use in,cm,and mm as size formats